# Java Regexp pattern in Android

Tags: java, regex, string

What characters does block this pattern:

```
private static Map<String, String> parseMetadata(String metaString) {
    Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] metaParts = metaString.split(";");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)=\\'([^\\']*)\\'$");
    Matcher m;
    for (int i = 0; i < metaParts.length; i++) {
        m = p.matcher(metaParts[i]);
        if (m.find()) {
            metadata.put(((String) m.group(1)).trim(), ((String) m.group(2)).trim());
        }
    }

    return metadata;
}
```

I've tested and the string with ' symbol was blocked, but I don't want this to happen.

Comment: No need at all to escape the `'` here: `"([a-zA-Z]+)='([^']*)'$"` works equally well. Unless you do mean to have a backslash before a single quote?

Comment: Please provide an example input and output. Also explain how the output differs from what you expect.

Comment: Also, no need at all to cast the key and value in `metadata.put()` -- your `Map` has been declared as `Map<String, String>` anyway. Why the cast at all?

Comment: Other question: what on earth do you call a "string with ' symbol" anyway?

Comment: It's not my class code, I've taken it. I need to get MP3 id3 tags from the stream. So the artist names and songs mustn't be blocked, they must be equal their true values.

Comment: There was a song name like "It's good". So it was blocked

Comment: OK, wait. Are song titles between single quotes or double quotes?

Comment: It's rather difficult to say, only to check somehow. I can give the link for full class code

Comment: What equally does Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)=\\'([^\\']*)\\'$"); do? As I understand, this preserves only some letters/pattern in input string.

Comment: I mean it permits only some "special" input strings

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what you want.

First of all: `'` has no special meaning in a regex. Your original regex could therefore be:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)='([^']*)'$
```

If you mean to capture strings with quoted single quotes in them, provided these single quotes are quoted with a backslash, you can use this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)='([^']*(?:\\'[^']*)*)'$
```

In a Java string:

```
"([a-zA-Z]+)='([^']*(?:\\\\'[^']*)*)'$"
```

Comment: The output must be an artist name and title of the song. I guess that the pattern blocks some unwanted symbols

Comment: The start string can be artist='Chris Mc'Donald'; It has ' sign inside ''. How to save this string for further processing? More over, there can be more than one '